# Ahhh! I lost my consecutive days streak

Tags: support

I had over 3950 consecutive days visited. That's over 10 years. And today I looked and I was at 2!?!
I've been on the site every day.  How did this happen?
I'm really  bummed.

I've got browser history that shows it too.

Comment: Wow! Also, wondering what motivates one to log in 10 yrs straight.

Comment: I have had similar issues, and my takeaway is that maybe I should get out more.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - I like to think I get out plenty.  It took a little work sometimes to stay “current” but I managed it while on several trips overseas, day trips motorcycling with my brother. Vacation with my family. I hike. I fish. I bicycle. And I try never to say, “hang in while I log in to ELU”

Comment: It **might** be relevant that the Stack Exchange counts days according to UTC: if you visited the site every calendar day according to your local time, but there was a gap of more than 24 hours, encompassing a whole calendar day of UTC, between two visits, that would count as a missed day.

Comment: @jsw29-  yes.  I think that’s it.  Sad.  I was on Sat at 2pm my time and then at 9pm on Sunday.  I’m UTC-7.

Comment: I lost about 60 consecutive days for the same reason--much less than you, but I was going for that shiny gold "fanatic" badge. It does mention on [the badge page](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/badges) that days are counted in UTC, so it was my bad for not paying close enough attention.

Comment: Probably your 3950 consecutive days is a record on SE sites…

Comment: @user66974 - I think VonC was at 4444 back in July 2021 on Stack Overflow.  Maybe for ELU? But I don't know, there are a few others that are "always on" as well.